# Error: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I am having this error:
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345

```
if (menu.authenticated && menu.canView?.includes(profile?.accountType)) {
    |                                              ^**Error is here**
123 |            return loggedInUser && <MenuItem key={menu.resource} {...menu} />;
124 |       } else {
125 |         return !loggedInUser && <MenuItem key={menu.resource} {...menu} />;
```

Comment: what's the data type of `menu.authenticated` and `menu.canView`?

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `menu.canView?.includes` has to be of type `string`, but `profile?.accountType` is of type `string | undefined`.

You can fix the condition with

```
if (menu.authenticated && profile && menu.canView?.includes(profile.accountType)) {
```

Comment: maybe `&& profile.accountType` as well